# How can I change version of Microsoft SQL server from 14 to 5.1 for using on Windows XP?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Good Day. I used Microsoft SQL server 2014 to create Database in C# app. Because of this, my app doesn't work on XP and shows different errors. How can I change version of Microsoft SQL server from 14 to 5.1 for using on Windows XP?

Comment: Re-Installation...

Comment: SQL Server 5.1? I thought I might might be mistaken, but there never was a Version 5.1: [History of Microsoft SQL Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#Release_summary). Version  6.0, however, came out in 1995, so I really don't believe you are trying to change to a version that came out 25 odd years ago. On the other hand Version 14 is SQL Server 2017, however, you've stated you have 2014. This doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database?view=sql-server-2017 you can go back to an older version of SQL Server for compatibility.  On my current instance (2012), I can go back to 2005 or 2008 compatibility.

1. **Right-click** the database you want to change
2. Choose **Properties**
3. Go to **Options**
4. Change the Compatibility using the **Compatibility Level** drop-down